# Вывести дату-время объекта GregorianCalendar в установленных часовом поясе и формате?

Tags: java, дата, время, формат, часовые-пояса

Если использовать метод getTime(), то выводиться будет соответствующий объект клаccа Date. А так как он кроме long-значение миллисекунд никаких настроек не имеет, то часовой пояс и формат получаться локальными (в независимости от установок GregorianCalendar объекта).

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.FRENCH);
        GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-8"), Locale.JAPAN);
        GregorianCalendar c3 = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC-15"), Locale.TAIWAN);

        System.out.println(c1.getTime()); // Wed Jun 12 20:35:44 MSK 2019
        System.out.println(c2.getTime()); // Wed Jun 12 20:35:44 MSK 2019
        System.out.println(c3.getTime()); // Wed Jun 12 20:35:44 MSK 2019

    }

}

// Никакой разницы в выводах
```

**Как выводить объект календаря, чтобы увидеть реальное представление (то есть что бы в вышеприведённом коде, строки вывода отображали разные, установленные, часовые пояса и форматы)?**

Comment: забудьте про `Calendar`. На дворе 2019 год - java.time вам в помощь!

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, а чем конкретно плох Calendar? без голословности

Comment: вот что пишет оракл: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html